# Direct vs indirect database access

Tags: data-access

I'll take as example the following scenario. A company develops a component A deployed in its clients (this component is located in the client area, and this client may not be trusted by the company). The component needs to access data stored in a database server located in the company area (trusted area).  One of the core modules developed by the company is the data model, using Hibernate as ORM.

One approach is that component A depends directly on the data model module and accesses the database directly (through Hibernate). The second approach is to access the database indirectly, using an intermediary module that interfaces component A and the database server.

Which problems may appear by connecting the component directly to the database server? What are the advantages of using an API? What do you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is commonly called 3-tier or n-tier architecture. There are many benefits chief among them being scalability  (by distributing the API module on many servers or even cloud), caching, centralised update and version management, security etc. In many companies the database  is firewalled from client machines and you cannot even connect to it.
The issues are more system complexity, more components to develop and support etc. You should google on N-tier architecture for more details and judge if it suitable for you.

Comment: I'm aware about the existence of multi-tier architecture, but it seems different for me because here, it doesn't imply a single physical machine. Do you think the data access layer has to be distributed to the clients? Generally, the data access layer accesses directly the database (through an ORM tool sometimes), but accessing the database directly from the client (using the data access layer) lets me think that security issues may appear.

Comment: Security can be compromised if the client machine is not under your control and there is direct database connection possible from the client machine. The API module (even if it is in a separate process than the client application) can be tampered, reverse engineered etc. Using the N-tier architecture you can have an API tier that accesses the DB and client can only access the API tier using a well defined API, appropriate security possibly auditing to let it perform only well defined actions,nothing more, nothing less. The DAL would then be an implementation detail in your API tier.

Comment: BTW when I say API I mean some form of remote API using either low level transports like sockets, RMI/.Net remoting, or more higher level like SOAP, REST etc.

Comment: By this API, you mean the data access layer (possibly DAOs)?Or, an interface at a higher level (for example, component A use an API on a server-side module, and the latter use the data access layer to access the database)? Also, do you think the overhead added by the interface module has to be taken into account?